# Flutter - web app - what's the best practice for displaying a modal data entry form?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a web app with Flutter, and I was wondering what the best options are for displaying a modal data entry form that does not need to take the whole screen space.

Initially, I was looking at pushing another Scaffold based screen, but that takes up the whole screen space.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My humble solution is to wrap your Scaffold's body's Widgets in a Stack.

You can choose whether or not to display the form using `if (someState) ...` inside the children list.

The form itself can be wrapped in a Card that is wrapped in a Center Widget.

There might be better solutions but that's what I use.

Comment: How about show modal bottom sheet as a container for an input form?

Comment: @user2868835, my understanding of your comment is to wrap the input form inside some sort of container Widget. That sounds logical yes. But how will you add it to screen is the question.

Comment: In my case, I start with a screen that shows a list of data entities.  Clicking on a data entity in the list will open up an 'edit entity' form.  The question is about how best to present the form.  I started by having another Scaffold screen as the vehicle for the edit form, but for a web app that makes no sense as the form width is too large. Hence, the idea of using a modal bottom sheet to display the form.